# Wait for $scope to really apply changes in html

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a problem trying to detect when the `$scope` variable really affect the html.
I need to access to the element after the $scope really apply the changes to the html, but the `$scope.$watch` is not doing the trick.

JS:

```
$scope.variable = "<p id='myElement'>Hello world!</p>";
console.log(jQuery('#myElement')[0]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html="varible | trustAsHtml"></div>
```

The problem is that, even if the `$scope` is applying the new content, the element still doesn't exist and jQuery returns `undefined`, so i need to wait untill the `$scope` really apply the changes to the html.

I know that a solution could be the `$timeout` but it's not really reliable, there is something that could help me?

Comment: Why do you need a jQuery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dunno why you need jQuery - there is probably an easier way with angular but there you go: angular has private method called `$$postDigest`, since all the DOM and model changes happens during `$digest` cycle it should do what you want, the other method would be to use `$timeout`, I've made working plunker for you

http://plnkr.co/edit/oZ2xfoUQxcOzNw7eXCmT?p=preview

```
$scope.htmlvar = $sce.trustAsHtml('<strong>Test</strong>');

$timeout(function () {
  console.log('timeout', jQuery('strong').text())
}, 0, false) //false to not run another digest

$scope.$$postDigest(function () {
  console.log('postDigest', jQuery('strong').text())
})
```

Comment: This was just an example, i actually need it for videojs ```videojs('#myElement', {}, .... ``` this is why i need to know when the element really exists

Comment: Cool, I've extended my answer by `$timeout` which does the same thing but IMHO it's more stable as it's not private angular method, check it out

Comment: fwiw I just tried `$$postDigest` and not all of the elements had updated

Comment: As you can see 5 years have passed since I wrote that answer, things could have changed, could you provide some reproducible scenario on plunker code pen or jsfiddle?